# Proper usage of 'continue' and 'break' in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to write a for loop which has a 'continue' and a 'break' in it. The code is as followed

```
b = 0 
for a in range(1,20):
    if a == 1:
        b =1
        print b
    elif a == 2:
        b = 2
        print b
    elif a == 3:
        b = 3
        print b
    else:
        continue
    a +=1
    print "a = (%d) " % (a)
    if a ==10:
        print "a = (%d) " % (a)
        break
```

What I wanna do is to loop over `a` and using `a` as a condition to determin the value of `b`. Also I don't want `a` to reach 20, so I add another condition `if a == 10` to end the loop earlier. However, the result printed out is not exactly as what I want:

```
1
a = (2) 
2
a = (3) 
3
a = (4)
```

which means the

```
if a ==10:
    print "a = (%d) " % (a)
    break
```

is totolly missed. I don't know which line I wrote is incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `continue` means? It doesn't mean "keep going". Also, how do you think `a += 1` affects the ongoing `for` loop?

Comment: To hit the `break` statement, you'd need `a == 9` at the start of the loop.  However, `a == 9` corresponds to `else: continue` which skips the rest of the loop (including the `break` statement)... The best resolution here really depends on what you're trying to do, but if you add an `elif a == 9: pass` branch, you should start to see the `break` get hit.

Comment: `pass` means "just keep going", `continue` means jump to the next iteration and `break` means end the currently running loop completly. So, you shouldn't have used the `else: continue`. If you remove it, it will probably match your expectations _slightly_ more.

Comment: `continue` is a filter, `break` is a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of the code

```
if a ==10:
print "a = (%d) " % (a)
break
```

never gets to execute because of the condition specified for the continue statement. In other words, you are saying when a is not equal to 1, 2 or 3, the loops go back to executes which means it will never get to the next line after the continue statement. So, when a equals to 10, it will fulfill the condition of the continue statement and goes back to the loop to continue execution.

If you want to print out a when it is equal to 10, you may not need the continue statement. Try out this code:

```
b = 0 
for a in range(1,20):
    if a == 1:
        b =1
        print b
    elif a == 2:
        b = 2
        print b
    elif a == 3:
        b = 3
        print b
    a +=1
    print "a = (%d) " % (a)
    if a == 10:
        print "a = (%d) " % (a)
```

You can go through this resource http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm to better understand python for loop structures

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect line that you wrote is the continue statement.
What it does is stops the current iteration and takes you to next iteration of loop.As per your problem statement there is no need of continue statement.Try removing continue statement and it will run.
Below is the sample code:

```
for a in range(1,20):
if a == 1:
    b =1
    print b
elif a == 2:
    b = 2
    print b
elif a == 3:
    b = 3
    print b
else:
    a +=1
    print "a = (%d) " % (a)
    if a ==10:
      print "a = (%d) " % (a)
      break
```